# Selenium: Does it useful to catch NoSuchElementException appears for a clickable element?

Tags: selenium, nosuchelementexception

Why do we catch `NoSuchElementException`? It makes sense to catch the exception when we only verify the presence of an element in a particular page and not performing any actions on it. We can catch this exception and log a custom message like "Element not found"

When we are about to click an element and if it is not found in the page, selenium throws `NoSuchElementException`. What is the use of catching this exception instead of letting it to halt the test and failing the testcase?

Note: My subsequent steps depends on this clicking step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason to catch the exception is to provide more relevant test failure output. For example, if a `div` element  isn't found in a page of 20-30 divs, cause the selector doesn't match that specific div, you could let the exception remain uncaught with a generic error message or you could catch it and throw a different exception with error message "navbar is missing".

If it is clear from the generic error message what is wrong, or you have a test failure message that explains it, there is no reason to catch it.

A different reason to catch this exception is that it's part of skip code (skip this test if/unless). So you look for an element and if it's present you proceed with the test, if it's not - you skip it.

There may be other reasons, but these are two common ones.

Comment: If this is the case, do we need to surround every `findElement` statement with `try-catch` block?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Exceptions:

1.Checked Exceptions

2.Unchecked Exceptions

Checked Exceptions are checked at compile time only, **these should be handled by the programmer**. Compiler will check at compile time whether these exceptions are handled or not if not compile time error occurs. Some of the checked exceptions are IOException, FileNotFoundExpection,etc.

Unchecked Exceptions:
Unchecked exceptions are not checked by compiler at the time of compilation. the exceptions which are extended by RuntimeException class are all unchecked exceptions. Some of the unchecked exceptions are AritmeticException, NullPointerException etc. In selenium we see unchecked exceptions such as NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException , NoSuchWindowException, TimeoutException etc.

***In short, Checked exceptions must be caught. RuntimeException, also called unchecked exceptions, should not be caught***

More info can be found on

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/exception-handling-selenium-webdriver/
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/java-tutorials/exception-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java-examples

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the types of exceptions. Could you please answer for the scenario explained in the question?